# Python, Pandas, sql, read specific columns from a database with a for-loop

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database, database-cursor

my goal is to read only certain column names with pd.read_sql

```
## FILTER VALUES ##
#filtering all columns with temperature
filter_temp_values = df_column[df_column[0].str.contains("temperature")]
#filtering all columns with humidity
filter_humi_values = df_column[df_column[0].str.contains("humidity")]

result = cursor.fetchall()
for x in filter_temp_values[0]:
    #y = tuple(list(x))
    y = "SELECT '%s' FROM Raummonitoring" %(x)
    test = cursor.execute(y)
```

result:

> InternalError: Unread result found

i tried also:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
for x in filter_temp_values[0]:
    y = tuple(list(x))
    z = f"SELECT ${y} FROM Raummonitoring"
    test = pd.read_sql(z, con = engine)
```

result:

> ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1370 (42000): execute command denied to user 'xxxx'@'%' for routine 'xxxx.$'
> [SQL: SELECT $('t', 'e', 'm', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'a', 't', 'u', 'r', 'e', '*', 'e', 'r', 's', '*', 'l', 'i', 't', 'e', '*', '3', '*', 'w', 'e', 'r', 'm', 's', 'e', 'r', '*', '0', '*', 'e', 'l', 's', 'y', 's', '_', '0') FROM Raummonitoring]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

what is my fault ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be running into an issue with casting a string column name over to a tuple of its characters.

Would something like this work where you join the list of joins with a "," first, and then just make 1 submission to your database?

```py
column_names = ['temperature_1', 'temperature_2', 'temperature_3']
y = ', '.join(column_names)
z = f"SELECT {y} FROM Raummonitoring"
    
print(z)
```

> SELECT temperature_1, temperature_2, temperature_3 FROM Raummonitoring

Comment: ty for youre help! i answered it and used your  tip with f"{<variable>}"